# Django Signal on method call (not triggering model instance)

Tags: django, django-signals

We have a model:

```
class Item(model.Model):
    pass

    def items_red(self):
        # filter items by red color
        # model instance is NOT changed (saved)
        pass
```

I need to catch `Item.items_red()` method execution with Django signal.
Any suggestions how to do that? `items_red` not changing model instance in any way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a custom signal:

```
import django.dispatch

items_red_executed = django.dispatch.Signal()

class Item(model.Model):
    pass

    def items_red(self):
        # filter items by red color
        # model instance is NOT changed (saved)
        items_red_executed.send(sender=self.__class__)
```

then a receiver:

```
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(items_red_executed, sender=Item)
def my_receiver(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs.get('sender'))
```

For more information refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals).

Comment: Thx for an explanation, I don't use signals a lot. But now I understand its a bit overhead and would just create additional method, and trigger one in `items_red`

Comment: I don't think you have to worry much about that overhead, in DB-driven applications the biggest bottleneck is usually caused by your DB performance.

Comment: Still, code should as explicit as possible. It's helps when you support your project after couple month of coding